# Swiftでプロトコルに準拠したクラスの配列を定義したい

Tags: swift, ios, ジェネリクス

プロトコルを定義してそのプロトコルに準拠したクラスの配列を定義したいのですが、良い書き方はありますでしょうか？

プロトコルの定義は以下のような実装で、複数のプロパティとメソッドが定義されています。

```
protocol ProtocolA {
    var property: AnyObject { get }
    func someMethod()   
}
```

実際にはこのような形でViewにプロトコルに準拠したクラスの配列を保持したいです。

```
class View: UIView {
    var objects ←　これをProtocolAに準拠したクラスの配列にしたい
}
```

このような形も考えましたが、Storyboard上での使用も考え諦めました。

```
class View<T: ProtocolA>: UIView {
    var objects = [T]()
}
```

使用用途としては

```
class View: UIView {
    func someMethod<T: ProtocolA>(objects: [T]) {
        // このobjectsをプロパティとして保持したい
    } 
}
```

ジェネリクスを使用したプログラミング経験があまりなく不可解な説明があるかもしれませんが、よろしくおねがいします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

普通に、ProtocolAの配列を使う形でどうでしょうか？
（Xcode7 beta6で動作を確認）

```
protocol ProtocolA {
    var property: AnyObject { get }
    func someMethod()
}

class View: UIView {
//  var objects ←　これをProtocolAに準拠したクラスの配列にしたい
    var objects = [ProtocolA]()     // ProtocolAの配列を作成

    func someMethod(objects: [ProtocolA]) {
        // このobjectsをプロパティとして保持したい
        self.objects = objects      // ProtocolAの配列をコピー
    }

    // MARK: - 以下、コメントへの回答として追加

    /// 保存したプロパティをメソッド引数として渡す
    func execOtherMethod() {
        if let obj = objects.last {
            otherMethod(obj)
        }
    }

    /// Protocolを直接使用する
    func otherMethod(object: ProtocolA) {
        object.someMethod()
    }

    /// Genericsを使うパターン（コンパイルエラーになる）
//  func otherMethod<T: ProtocolA>(object: T) {
//      object.someMethod()
//  }

}

/// ProtocolAに準拠したクラス
class ClassA: ProtocolA {
    var property: AnyObject { return "A" }
    func someMethod() { print("A")  }
}

// someMethodを呼び出し
let vi = View()
let obj = ClassA()
vi.someMethod([obj])

// Protocolを引数に使うテスト
vi.execOtherMethod()
```

Comment: プロトコルを配列として定義すると実装はできたのですが、以下のような特定の条件で動作することができません。

保存したプロパティをメソッド引数として渡す
`self.otherMethod(self.objects.last)`
メソッドは引数としてProtocolAに準拠したクラス
`func otherMethod<T: ProtocolA>(object: T) { }`

Comment: こちらでも確認しましたが、プロトコルからジェネリックスを呼び出す部分でコンパイルエラーになっているようです。直接、プロトコルを使うことで回避出来ました。回答のソースコードを修正したので参考してください。